# Xlib xinput test device status if it got hanged

Tags: linux, xlib, xinput

How to check if keyboard (for examle) is not hanged?

Maybe it is possible to send something to device and check response using pselect()?

I'm using xinput extensions (1,2) do they provide some facility for such a task?

Comment: What do you mean by *hanged*? Turned off? Disconnected? Broken?

Comment: More likely broken, or some line error, not responding but visible in device list.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently looking for this. You can get the responding keyboards id by running this in bash.

```
kbname=$(cat /proc/bus/input/devices |
grep -Poi '(?<=N:\sName=")(.*keyboard.*)(?="$)') &&
xinput list |
grep -Poi '(?<='$kbname')(?:\s+id=\K)(\d+)'
```

Comment: Xinput uses XIQueryDevice(...) to get list from /proc/bus/input/devices, so this doesn't help. I've just changed task so my program relies on XIQueryDevice results, and puts all XIMasterKeyboard-type devices in desired array.